# Cascade.ALL doesn't work with Spring Data JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I have following entities:

User:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email = "";

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nickname = "";

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password = "";

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<NewsSource> newsSources;

    // getters and setters
}
```

News Source:

```
@Entity
public class NewsSource {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private URL url;

    private LocalDateTime updateTime;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<News> newses;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<User> users;
}
```

UsersRepository and NewsSourcesRepository are simple JpaRepositories from Spring Data JPA. Their configuration is as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:database_config.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"news.repositories" })
public class RepositoriesConfiguration {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    DataSource dataSource(Environment env) {
        HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
        dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSourceConfig.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        dataSourceConfig.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
        dataSourceConfig.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

        return new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, Environment env) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("pl.mielecmichal.news.entities");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Inside my test last assert gives an error. Users collection is empty, but in my opinion it should contains one user (saved few lines earlier). Cheers!

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void cascadeRelationsShouldBeRetrieved() throws MalformedURLException {
    NewsSource source = new NewsSource();
    URL someUrl = new URL(SOME_URL);
    source.setUrl(someUrl);
    newsSourcesRepository.save(source);
    newsSourcesRepository.flush();

    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(EMAIL);
    List<NewsSource> sources = new ArrayList<>();
    sources.add(source);
    user.setNewsSources(sources);
    usersRepository.save(user);
    usersRepository.flush();

    User savedUser = usersRepository.findOne(EMAIL);
    NewsSource newsSource = savedUser.getNewsSources().get(0);
    assertThat("News source should be saved", newsSource.getUrl(), is(someUrl));

    NewsSource savedSource = newsSourcesRepository.findOne(newsSource.getUrl());
    assertThat("New user should be saved in M2M relation", savedSource.getUsers(), Matchers.contains(user));
}
```

Comment: please share exception stack trace

Comment: There is no exception. savedSource.getUsers() is null, but should contains one user after usersRepository.save(user). As I understand it is bidirectional relation Many To Many

Comment: When you use ManyToMany annotation, one of them must be owning side and the other will reference by mappedBy. Please check this link http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/ . Only check the two uses of many to many annotation. you must use mappedBy in one of them otherwise things may not work as expected. You can check documentation if needed.

Comment: When I add mappedBy in User either NewsSource, I still get null instead of List.

Comment: you can enable show sql queries and put a debug point at the last assert. Now check your logs and play the debug (In eclipse it is resume. play icon). are you seeing any query being fired?

Comment: Inserts are fired and I see inserting values to M2M table. The problem is  newsSourcesRepository.findOne(newsSource.getUrl()); does not fire any query (should fire select)

Comment: it might be getting from the session instead of going to database. Can you a debug point at last assert and check the contents of users in savedSource. Is it null or some collection reference?

Comment: It is null. I think it could be connected with @Transactional annotation on this test case.

Comment: can you plz update the question with those suggested many to many changes. so that it could help someone else instead of they reporting it again to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98497/discussion-between-prem-kumar-and-michal-mielec).

Comment: michal i think i found the issue.. can you join the chat?

Comment: i think i found the issue. what is ur join table name? is it something like "User_ NewsSource" or "NewsSource_User" ? if any other what is it?